# regex: ignore eveything except the second column

Tags: regex

I have a txt file with some text like this:

000001 - AAAAAA - BBBBBBBB - CCCC
000002 - BAAAAA - BBBBBBBB - CCCC
000003 - DAAAAA - BBBBBBBB - CCCC
...

I need a regex that ignore everything except the second colunm(AAAAAA,BAAAAA,DAAAAA,...)

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I only find a way to select the first column and the last one.  (^.{0,9}) and (^.{0,9})?([^-]*$)

Comment: What tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: None. It is for using on BeyondCompare program. I am currently testing online here: https://regex101.com/r/1G4HfJ/1

Comment: You can't unmatch some text in the middle of a match, what features does BeyondCompare offer here? Can you concat captures? Or can you replace with backreferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[^-]+- ([^ -]+).*
```

`[^-]+` matches up to the first non-dash and `[^- ]+` matches up to the first character which is neither a space nor a dash.

With a tool like sed the command would be

```
sed -E 's/[^-]+- ([^ -]+).*/\1/' input.txt
```

An even better tool for the job, however, is awk which will give the same result with the command

```
awk -F ' - ' '{ print $2 }' input.txt
```